# How to scroll a Recyclerview which is inside multi-level nested fragment and Viewpager?

Tags: android

I am trying to hide a toolbar when i scroll up the recyclerview . This recycler view is inside a Fragment (named Fragment 2) . This fragment gets re-used in a Viewpager with 3 Tabs(re-using the same fragment) which is in a Fragment(named Fragment 1) . Now this Fragment 1 is loaded in a Framelayout which is hosted in an Activity

**EDIT 1:** Even the recycler view is not scrolling in this case. The last items never show up. I cannot scroll to the end of the last items

I tried using coordinator layouts and Nested scroll view but nothing gave the results.

**Activity Main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/MainBG"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".iccrankings.ICCRankingNew">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/cardBGC">


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_icc_categories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                android:overlapAnchor="false"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </Spinner>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container_of_ranks_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fragment 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".iccrankings.fragments.RankViewPagerContainerFragment">




    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_all_matches"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/odi_tab" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_tab" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t20_tab" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/categoryDataContainerPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs_all_matches" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".iccrankings.fragments.IccHumanFragment">



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/icc_human_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>






</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am [attaching an image which illustrates the nested views and desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nJ07.jpg) which describes the composition of the views and the desired results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your activities toolbar inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and set required flags for scrolling behavior.

See this page for more details :

https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` right in your AppBarLayout.

It should look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/cardBGC">


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_icc_categories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                android:overlapAnchor="false"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </Spinner>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This always hides the Toolbar

Comment: Also. i updated the question. My Recyclerview is not scrolling to the last most item

Comment: @abk007 it may be that this doesn't work because you're using CoordinatorLayout as RecyclerView's container. Also you should set layout_behavior to your RecyclerVieiw too.

Comment: Here I published my layout files from working project. Look at them these, maybe you'll find what's wrong your layouts. gist:https://gist.github.com/khojiakbar17/c95b80697caca253bee4eceb52ed3014

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that without `Collapsing Toolbar`, for example you can make your toolbar hide if you scroll down with some code like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddd"
    tools:context=".ControllerAdding.ControllerPickerActivity"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#df1b39"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/pureWhite"
            style="@style/RobotoBoldTextAppearance"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Products List"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

be sure to add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in your Toolbar because if you don't and then you add a RecyclerView here, that Recycler won't be Scrollable.

this is a tested code that i used for my own app, so if you see some styling or ... its because of that.